# No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed `tensorflow (1.6.0)` in `Visual Studio 2017`, but I get the following error when I run the code:

> No module named `tensorflow`

Any help?

Comment: wich operating system you have !!

Comment: @SakhriHoussem visual studio I'd guess windows

Comment: @quantik VS Code is available on many OS's, and many people confuse the two.

Comment: @jhpratt I don't think I've met a single person who has used VS on mac or linux. What other OS could it possibly be on? But fair point I guess

Comment: @quantik A ton of people use VS Code on Linux. I can't speak for Mac, though. Let's stay on topic.

Comment: Windows 10 @SakhriHoussem

Comment: and which version of python you use

Comment: python 3.6 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

1. you must install it on `Python 64bit`  version `n`
   **example**: [python3.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/) on Windows
   1.1. on cmd `cd C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts`
   1.2. execute this commande `pip install tensorflow`
2. then in the `IDE` you must select the right version of `Python` (ex: the version when you install `tensorflow` `python3.6 64bit`)

check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project) maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

Check that you installed it in the same runtime that Visual studio is using for the code i.e. Visual studio may be pointing to one python installation, but you installed tf on a different python installation.